# Joining files fail with "h264_mp4toannexb filter failed to receive output packet"

Tags: ffmpeg

I've always joined my MOV recordings with

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '$PWD/%s'\n" ./*.mov) -c copy o.mov
```

however, due to a small glitch in one particular file, I get **h264_mp4toannexb filter failed to receive output packet**. I may discard the part with the glitch, which is around 01m40s into the file. Copying the problematic input file with `-c copy` works, but using the new output for joining still fails.

Things I tried without success:

- `-fflags discardcorrupt`
- `-err_detect ignore_err`
- `-ignore_unknown`
- `-copy_unknown`
- `-ss 00:03:00`

A Google search for the error above only returns the source code itself for the `concat` option: ftp://opensource.tambov.ru/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/libavformat/concatdec.c

Answer (score 2):

One easy workaround I found while writing this question is simply discarding the broken piece of the input file before trying to concatenate the files, **in a separate command**, since `-f concat` and `-ss 00:03:00` don't work together when *"h264_mp4toannexb filter failed to receive output packet"* is present.

For example, to discard the first 3 minutes of the file, then concatenate separately:

```
$ ffmpeg -i broken.mov -c copy -ss 00:03:00 fixed.mov
$ mv broken.mov broken.mov.ignore
$ ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i <(printf "file '$PWD/%s'\n" ./*.mov) -c copy o.mov
```

I still can't understand why concatenating is the only operation that fails with that error, but the source code linked above might give some hint.